# How to proceed when the train image is too large to feed into the network once?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, unet-neural-network

I'm using [voxelmorph](https://github.com/voxelmorph/voxelmorph) to do lung image registration. But my train images are too large to feed into the network, the images have different shape, and the shapes are not regular. Some are 513,436...(not a power of 2, so I can not directly use U-NET or other CNN).

To address these problems, I split the train images into 128x128x128 sub-images with step=100. it looks like this:

[split image into sub-images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsEdJ.png)

In the predict phase, I also split the image into some sub-images, used the network to predict every sub-image, and then combined the results. But the problem is that the boundaries of the sub-images look different with the internal region, like this:

[boundaries problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geTw6.png)

My naive approach is smoothing, but I found it does not work. I think this is a common problem. How to fix this? Please help.

This data problem is a little different.Because the shape of a simple train image is more than 300x300x300. So not the whole dataset is too big, a  simple data is too big.

there are some example:

```
(430, 318, 168)  
(434, 354, 349)  
(428, 290, 439)  
(446, 290, 466)  
(452, 382, 373)  
(464, 290, 378)  
(424, 278, 217)  
(308, 202, 109)  
(420, 312, 537)  
(444, 314, 399)  
(418, 368, 323)  
(384, 432, 396)  
(412, 282, 408)  
(314, 188, 239)  
(428, 308, 422)  
(412, 302, 471)  
(276, 158, 127)  
(384, 432, 396)  
(394, 322, 370)  
(412, 322, 289)  
(412, 296, 458)  
(323, 250, 127)  
(448, 296, 431)  
(420, 302, 446)  
(438, 314, 393)  
(386, 424, 386)
```

The bone Net like this :

```
def conv_block(x_in, nf, strides=1):
    """
    specific convolution module including convolution followed by leakyrelu
    """
    ndims = len(x_in.get_shape()) - 2
    assert ndims in [1, 2, 3], "ndims should be one of 1, 2, or 3. found: %d" % ndims

    Conv = getattr(KL, 'Conv%dD' % ndims)
    x_out = Conv(nf, kernel_size=3, padding='same',
                 kernel_initializer='he_normal', strides=strides)(x_in)
    x_out = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x_out)
    return x_out

def unet_core(vol_size, enc_nf, dec_nf, full_size=True, src=None, tgt=None, src_feats=1, tgt_feats=1):
    """
    unet architecture for voxelmorph models presented in the CVPR 2018 paper. 
    You may need to modify this code (e.g., number of layers) to suit your project needs.
    :param vol_size: volume size. e.g. (256, 256, 256)
    :param enc_nf: list of encoder filters. right now it needs to be 1x4.
           e.g. [16,32,32,32]
    :param dec_nf: list of decoder filters. right now it must be 1x6 (like voxelmorph-1) or 1x7 (voxelmorph-2)
    :return: the keras model
    """
    ndims = len(vol_size)
    assert ndims in [1, 2, 3], "ndims should be one of 1, 2, or 3. found: %d" % ndims
    upsample_layer = getattr(KL, 'UpSampling%dD' % ndims)

    # inputs
    if src is None:
        src = Input(shape=[*vol_size, src_feats])
    if tgt is None:
        tgt = Input(shape=[*vol_size, tgt_feats])
    x_in = concatenate([src, tgt])


    # down-sample path (encoder)
    x_enc = [x_in]
    for i in range(len(enc_nf)):
        x_enc.append(conv_block(x_enc[-1], enc_nf[i], 2))

    # up-sample path (decoder)
    x = conv_block(x_enc[-1], dec_nf[0])
    x = upsample_layer()(x)
    x = concatenate([x, x_enc[-2]])
    x = conv_block(x, dec_nf[1])
    x = upsample_layer()(x)
    x = concatenate([x, x_enc[-3]])
    x = conv_block(x, dec_nf[2])
    x = upsample_layer()(x)
    x = concatenate([x, x_enc[-4]])
    x = conv_block(x, dec_nf[3])
    x = conv_block(x, dec_nf[4])

    # only upsampleto full dim if full_size
    # here we explore architectures where we essentially work with flow fields 
    # that are 1/2 size 
    if full_size:
        x = upsample_layer()(x)
        x = concatenate([x, x_enc[0]])
        x = conv_block(x, dec_nf[5])

    # optional convolution at output resolution (used in voxelmorph-2)
    if len(dec_nf) == 7:
        x = conv_block(x, dec_nf[6])

    return Model(inputs=[src, tgt], outputs=[x])
```

There is a article refering the large image in CNN,[A New Approach to Compute CNNs for Extremely Large Images](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3132847.3132872).[image: A same boundary problem]It fix the boundary problem using a adptive padding, but the description is not clear. I think it is similar to overlap strategy.

Comment: If voxelmorph is achieving the outcome of conventional registration, eg registering a moving image to a fixed image, then sounds like you just need to resize the input image, so that the shape conforms to the input shape of the neural net.

Comment: VoxelMorph just use the U-NET as bone, If the images have the special shape (multiple of 2), they can be trained using VoxelMorph. But the shape of my train images do not meet this, the shape are different and not the multiple of 2 and the major are the image is too large to train. If I split it, the last result combined from the results of sub-images has the 'boundaries' .

Comment: How do you combine prediction images? How many down/up sampling layers does your backbone net have?

Comment: Just have 4 samplng layers.

Comment: @ruokuanwu If you have 4 downsampling layers it means that 16px on each end of the image will be effected. I would recommend sampling at step of 96px (128-16*2) and only using inner 96x96 squere when stitching your prediction leaving out 16px on each side as noisy or irrelevant. Please, let us know if you try it

Comment: @y.selivonchyk should I use the 128x128x128 sub-image with step of 96x96x96 and drop the 16px on each axis(3 axes here)? I think there may be a gap, because the original square is 128x128, after drop the 16px on each side, the final region is 96x96, It is not dense. is it right?

Comment: @y.selivonchyk I used your method,It's fine at least looking good. I will do a quantitative analysis. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If your problem can be solved by making the shapes size a multiple of 2, I would suggest using openCV.

You can simply expand image by adding white / black border. You can also scale image, depending on what works better in your case.

Another option - Run ImageMagic to increase image size of smaller images.
Example:

```
magick convert -resize 400% smallImage.png Enlarged.png
```

This will increase size of smaller image by 4 times.

Comment: The difference between the train images is too large. If I use a maximum num as a standard length of a axis (multiple of 2), there are some images which have the smaller shape would be padded with many zero or other( constant-padding or reflect padding).

Comment: I think the main problem is not wether the shape is multiple of 2, the major is that a simple train image is too large to train once. When I split it into sub -images, and then combine the sub-results., there is a 'boundary-problem'.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Hello @ruokuanwu this is very common problem that we have a lot of data to train in deep learning and we are not able to store all that into our memory at once. Data maybe in TeraBytes so that to solve this problem keras has a function of `flow_from_directory` by this function keras will be able to take batches directly from the disk. Now we don't have to upload all the data at once. This fucntion take a batch from the disk load it into the memory and feed it to the model for processing. In this way problem of training on big data set is resolved.

You can See the example here of traning through Image Generator.

[Example Notebook Kaggle Link](https://www.kaggle.com/sohaibanwaar1203/drd-c-vgg16)

**Requirements:**

if you are working on image classification you have to put your every class in separate folder and give the path of parent folder in which your separate classes folder is located.

Comment: There are some differences, I add some details about the data.

Answer (score 0):

With a U-net model it would be Ok to split the input into pieces and process them separately.

One thing to watch out for is the border of the image: splitting 256x256 into 4 images 128x128 might produce noticable border (a cross in the center of the image) in segmentation. To avoid that it would make sense to split image with a slight overlap and ignore the border.

In other words. For an image of size 256x256 while largest possible input that fit into memory is 128 follow the next algorithm:

1. Pick a border size. For a unet with 4 downsampling layers it would be reasonable to pick a border proportional to 2^number_of_downsamplings=2^4=16.
2. Split input image into squares of 96x96 where 96=128-2*border_size
3. for each square attach another 16px from each side form the original image. Resulting in an image of 128x128
4. After processing the image, cut out the inner square of 96x96 and use it to stitch the final prediction.